# Vaex: replace single character in column names

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I have a dataset with dot delimiter in column name, i.e. `name_1.0`. I understand that vaex changes these columns as `name_1_0`. I would like to use `.drop()` for my data frame. However, as I feel, it is not possible with column names that contain dot delimiter. How can I replace only one character in each column name? Is there an analog of pandas `.columns` ? I mean that in pandas it can be easily done by

`df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(',', '_')`

but it is quite impossible in my case (I have >50 columns) to use `df.rename` and explicitly change every column with dot delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know how you want to update each column name, you can loop over the column names and call the `df.rename` method:

```py
for column_name in df.column_names:
   new_column_name = column_name.replace(",", "_")
   df.rename(column_name, new_column_name)
```